# What is the real intention for admin-post.php?

Tags: plugin-development, admin, forms

While looking for proper form submission handling in plugins for users (frontend) I've stumbled upon this article [Handling POST Requests the WordPress Way](http://www.sitepoint.com/handling-post-requests-the-wordpress-way/), which encourages to use `admin-post.php` for this purpose. Taking a look into header we can find some kind of confirmation:

```
 /**
 * WordPress Generic Request (POST/GET) Handler
 *
 * Intended for form submission handling in themes and plugins.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Administration
 */
```

My main concern is that this method comes from admin part of WP code and its use in non-admin tasks makes some ambiguity.

Can anyone (especially WP authors) confirm that this approach intention is really holistic or admin only as I think?

Comment: I don't get the question. the code there is small and non ambiguous. If it fits your needs you can use it, if not, then not. The intentions of a code are usually documented in the code itself ;)

Answer (score 12):

`admin-post.php` is like a poor mans controller for handling requests.

It's useful in the sense that you don't need to process your request on an alternative hook such as `init` and check to see whether or not special keys exists on the superglobals, like:

```
function handle_request() {

    if ( !empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'xyz' ) {
        //do business logic
    }

}

add_action('init', 'handle_request');
```

Instead using admin-post.php affords you the ability to specify a callback function that will always be called on any request that supplies an action value that matches the suffix supplied to the action.

```
function handle_request() {

    //do business logic here...

}

add_action( 'admin_post_handle_request', 'handle_request' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_handle_request', 'handle_request' );
```

In the above example, we can forgoe the need to check for `!empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'xyz'` because at this point that processing has been taken care of for us.

That is the result of the specifying the action parameter and value and posting said value to the `admin-post.php` URL.

Additionally what is beneficial is that `admin-post.php` handles both `$_POST` and `$_GET` so it's not neccessary to check what kind of method the request is of course unless you want to for more complex processing.

Bottom line:

It is safe to use, it's just the name that throws you off.

By the way you should also remember to `wp_redirect()` the user back to an acceptable location as requesting `admin-post.php` will return nothing but a white screen as its response.

Comment: if you need to redirect you can not easily do output. I admit that I never heard of it before, but it doesn't sound like this end point is any improvement on writing your own form handler. It is very telling that core do not use it.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Indeed... you have to resort to transients, cookies/sessions or similar.

Comment: Telling Mark, the anti-transient man, to resort to transients is like forcing a dog to eat his own s*** ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen haha... in that case dare I say store everything to disk in the uploads directory _cue flames now_ :D

Comment: So, the WP Dev team intention is still unclear, the more that they don't mention anything on that in neither codex nor developer pages - at least, it is the recommended post handling for some future reasons. Current gain of using it is rather disputable than 'way to go' (because of redirects and transients), right?

Comment: @PieterGoosen, LOL, but dogs are strange and known to do anything :)

Comment: @KrzysztofPrzygoda, you are just trying to make your life complicated. It is in core since 2.6 but there is almost no documentation, and core doesn't use it therefor you better not use it yourself. Intentions of the people that made it are not important at all, the only question should be "is it useful".

Comment: I personally have been known to use these hooks, but I've only ever done so from the backend. I don't see a problem with it. Core doesn't use it probably because of the difficulty in backing out of their old architecture and or lack of desire for people to refactor (just speculating). It's there to be used, whether core utilize it themselves or not may have not been their direct intent but as methodology for you the integrator, sure... use it. As my comments indicate above it can be a clean way to handle certain kinds of requests. This is not a hard and fast rule though, do what suits you.

Comment: @MarkKaplun - that's why I ask here mislead (or not) by "Handling POST Requests the **WordPress Way**" title. Thx!

Comment: @KrzysztofPrzygoda there's never been a standard/best practice for handling post requests especially in the backend that is considered the "WordPress way". But just because core does not utilize these actions does not mean you shouldn't in some cases. People do all kinds of crazy form handling in WordPress for requests in the back and front end; there's little standards or consistency, just people doing crazy things on all manner of hooks. They are very convenient hooks especially if you don't need to return data with the redirect.

Comment: @userabuser, that is a little misleading, the settings API + post editing forms + term editing form cover most of the forms on admin side.With login having its own complex logic, user is probably the only one which might be attributed to inertia. The main problem with this not being used by core is that security plugins might close access to wp-admin. If they are doing it wrong, you will find it immediately in the case of the ajax end point, but you will not have a clue about this one.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I am talking about ambiguous requests for arbitrary actions, not core APIs. For example, in the admin users list table, I have a custom column, with a link that allows admins to approve user accounts before the user may access the site. This is one such usecase along with others where there is no "WordPress way". Also I don't think the main problem this method isn't used by core has much to do with security plugins unless they explicitly state otherwise, it's either a half-baked feature or it's exposed to developers in cases where there is no single best practice; hence the above.

Answer (score 2):

Seems fairly clear from the use of the `nopriv` handling (for non logged in users) in `admin-post.php` that this is indeed useable for both frontend and backend form handling, very similar to how `admin-ajax.php` can be used.

Comment: I admit that the code looks usable but... you have to admit that *user* doing some *admin* actions looks also suspicious, right? This is where the ambiguity comes from.

Comment: Yes I had similar thought when I first used `admin-ajax.php` - the admin part seems a bit misleading in both cases... it may help to think admin as in  as in `adminstration` rather than `administrator`...